# How to prevent rm from reporting that a file was not found?

Tags: bash, rm

I am using `rm` within a BASH script to delete many files. Sometimes the files are not present, so it reports many errors. I do not need this message. I have searched the man page for a command to make `rm` quiet, but the only option I found is `-f`, which from the description, "ignore nonexistent files, never prompt", seems to be the right choice, but the name does not seem to fit, so I am concerned it might have unintended consequences.

- Is the `-f` option the correct way to silence `rm`? Why isn't it called `-q`?
- Does this option do anything else?

Comment: you don't want to use -f, it removes file you marked as read only.

Comment: @pizza, only if you marked them read-only _badly_. If you use the permission system correctly, `rm` _can't_ remove a read-only file, even with `-f`; and if you're not doing it in a way the operating system actually enforces, is it really read-only at all?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The main use of `-f` is to force the removal of files that would
not be removed using `rm` by itself (as a special case, it "removes"
non-existent files, thus suppressing the error message).

You can also just redirect the error message using

```
$ rm file.txt 2> /dev/null
```

(or your operating system's equivalent). You can check the value of `$?`
immediately after calling `rm` to see if a file was actually removed or not.

Comment: `--f` is valid for GNU Coreutils `rm`, but only because it happens to be a unique abbreviation for `--force`. The short form `-f` is clearer and more portable.

Comment: Not sure I even realized that. `--f` here is just a typo for `-f`.

Comment: what does the 2 in `2>` do?

Comment: @Maverick It redirects any messages sent to stderr to /dev/null instead of sending them to the terminal.

Comment: It doesn’t print the error in terminal, but yet it stops the code execution like fatal error, so it doesn’t really solving the problem…

Comment: @Ido That's not a problem with `rm`. `rm` will remove what files it *can* (if you specified a mix of existing and non-existing files as arguments) before exiting with a non-zero exit code. If you are running your script with `set -e` (something I don't advise), you'll need to "guard" the command with something like `if rm ...; then ...; fi` to detect if there was an error or not without causing the shell itself to exit.

Answer (score 99):

Yes, `-f` is the most suitable option for this.

Comment: Some systems will prompt you when room even with -f till you use backslash.

Comment: @vimdude: It's not "some systems"; that behavior indicates that you have a shell function or alias that maps `rm` to `rm -i`.

Answer (score 36):

-f is the correct flag, but for the test operator, not rm

```
[ -f "$THEFILE" ] && rm "$THEFILE"
```

this ensures that the file exists and is a regular file (not a directory, device node etc...)

Comment: However, this has a race condition, and should not be used in production scripts.

Comment: I believe what @tripleee is pointing out is that the "-f" test and the file removal could complete in any order.  Another way to do it is: `if [ -f "$THEFILE" ]; then rm "$THEFILE"; fi`, which makes the test and the file removal steps explicitly sequential.

Comment: @robla that code does the same exact thing with more verbose syntax ... && != & ... The test will always happen before rm but a separate process could technically (though very unlikely) delete it before rm runs  (while the shell code after the test is being interpreted).

Comment: technosaurus - ooops, you're right.  What do you think is the best answer to @mmlac's question?

Comment: @robla This question currently has two answers with more than 40 upvotes; what makes you think either of those are not acceptable solutions to this question? My vote goes to "simply use `rm -f`" because discarding error messages could mask other errors. This answer is misleading in implying that there is something wrong with using `rm -f` and that somebody made a mistake and intended to use `test -f`.

Comment: And just to confirm, the race condition is that something could remove the file between `test` and `rm`. There is no way `rm` could execute before `test` here. Looking before you leap isa common mistake in concurrent programming -- you can't trust the result of the "look" any longer when you actually "leap"; the solution to that is to use locking or atomic operations. Which is precisely why you want `rm -f`, which is an example of the latter.

Answer (score 21):

`\rm -f file` will never report not found.

Comment: The -r is unnecessary and dangerous.

Comment: I assumed many files or directories. Reread user's request and you're right he was asking for files only. So corrected my answer

Comment: What is the backslash before the rm doing?? please guys I need an answer to that. On windows cygwin's make version 4.1 can't deal with \rm while 3.75 works just fine.

Comment: @AymanSalah The backslash in this context would escape any function or alias wrapping the real `rm` (as was popular on some sites in the early 1990s to prevent beginners from removing stuff and then calling up the sysadmin to get their files back).

Comment: Thank you - this solved my issue.. apparently the exit code allows for chaining using `&&` while without -f it breaks once the file is not found.

Answer (score 9):

As far as `rm -f` doing "anything else", it does force (`-f` is shorthand for `--force`) silent removal in situations where `rm` would otherwise ask you for confirmation. For example, when trying to remove a file not writable by you from a directory that is writable by you.

Answer (score -11):

I had same issue for cshell. The only solution I had was to create a dummy file that matched pattern before "rm" in my script.

Comment: Was that really the *only* solution? Did you try `rm -f` or `rm filename >&/dev/null`?

Comment: perhaps it's not the only solution, but it is sensible and readable and has no side effects.